# free() working in debugger but not in run mode

Tags: c, struct, union, expression-trees, infix-notation

I'm writing some code for a school project. It's an expression tree that holds digits and operators in infix notation. [Tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJHE2.png)

The tree has the folowing structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char the_operator;
    struct operand_node_tag *left_operand;
    struct operand_node_tag *right_operand;
} operator_node;

typedef struct operand_node_tag
{
    enum {operator_type, number_type} tree_node_type;
    union
    {
        operator_node the_operator_node;
        int the_number;
    };
} tree_node;
```

I've got a function that can dynamically can create a operator node:

```
tree_node *create_expression(char op, tree_node *l, tree_node *r)
{
    // Dynamically reserve memory for a tree_node of type operator_type.
   tree_node *newTreeNode = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
    if (newTreeNode == NULL)
    {           //Return NULL if there is no available memory.
    return NULL;
    }

    // Set the_operator to op, left_operand to l and right_operand to r
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.the_operator = op;
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.left_operand = l;
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.right_operand = r;
    newTreeNode->tree_node_type = operator_type;

    // and return the tree_node
    return newTreeNode;
}
```

And a function that can dynamically create a number node:

```
tree_node *create_number_node(int i)
{
    // Dynamically reserve memory for a tree_node of type number_type.
    tree_node *newTreeNode = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
    if (newTreeNode == NULL) {                                              //Return NULL if there is no available memory.
        return NULL;
    }
    //Set the node type to number
    newTreeNode->tree_node_type = number_type;

    // Set the_number to i and return the tree_node
    newTreeNode->the_number = i;
    // and return the tree_node
    return newTreeNode;
}
```

These functions are working fine for me. The problem comes when freeing the allocated memory. For which I've written the folowing function:

```
void free_expression_tree(tree_node **pnode)
    {
    // Free all dynamically reserved memory and set *pnode to NULL.
    if ((*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand && (*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
    {
    free_expression_tree(&(*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand);
    (*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand = NULL;
    }

    if ((*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand && (*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
    {
    free_expression_tree(&(*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand);
    (*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand = NULL;
    }

    printf("Free: ");
    if ((*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
        {
        printf("%c, ", (*pnode)->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        free(*pnode);
        printf("%d, \n", (*pnode)->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%d, ", (*pnode)->the_number);
        free(*pnode);
        printf("%d, \n", (*pnode)->the_number);

    }
    }
```

It loops through a given node and frees all nodes in lower levels. This functions seems to work fine in the debugger (GCC), giving the following result in the console:

```
Free: 12, 3277136, 
Free: 40, 3277136, 
Free: 23, 3277136, 
Free: 3, 3296384, 
Free: -, -18, 
Free: /, -18, 
Free: 2, -17891602, 
Free: *, -18, 
Free: +, -18,
```

I'm printing the number/operator just before and right after executing the free() function. Seems to work fine here.

Now here's the same result, but here I'm actually running the .exe:

```
Free: 12, 3735888, 
Free: 40, 3735888, 
Free: 23, 3735888, 
Free: 3, 3763520, 
Free: -, -, 
Free: /, /, 
Free: 2, 2, 
Free: *, *, 
Free: +, +,
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the compiler settings, yet I'm clueless to what. I've got optimizations turned off.

Do any of you have suggestions?

Complete code:
Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stack.h"
#include "tree.h"

int main(void)
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    tree_node *rootmin = create_expression('-', create_number_node(23), create_number_node(3));
    tree_node *rootdelen = create_expression('/', create_number_node(40), rootmin);
    tree_node *rootkeer = create_expression('*', rootdelen, create_number_node(2));
    tree_node *root = create_expression('+', create_number_node(12), rootkeer);
    printf("Infix:   ");
    print_tree_infix(root);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Postfix: ");
    print_tree_postfix(root);
    printf("\n");

    FILE *file = fopen("tree.graphviz", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can not create file tree.graphviz.");
        return -1;
    }

    create_visual_graph_from_tree(root, file);
    printf("Open file tree.graphviz op https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/#.\n");

    free_expression_tree(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

tree.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tree.h"
#include "stack.h"

tree_node *create_number_node(int i)
{
    // Dynamically reserve memory for a tree_node of type number_type.
    tree_node *newTreeNode = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
    if (newTreeNode == NULL) {                                              //Return NULL if there is no available memory.
        return NULL;
    }
    //Set the node type to number
    newTreeNode->tree_node_type = number_type;

    // Set the_number to i and return the tree_node
    newTreeNode->the_number = i;
    // and return the tree_node
    return newTreeNode;
}

tree_node *create_expression(char op, tree_node *l, tree_node *r)
{
    // Dynamically reserve memory for a tree_node of type operator_type.
   tree_node *newTreeNode = malloc(sizeof(tree_node));
    if (newTreeNode == NULL)
    {           //Return NULL if there is no available memory.
    return NULL;
    }

    // Set the_operator to op, left_operand to l and right_operand to r
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.the_operator = op;
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.left_operand = l;
    newTreeNode->the_operator_node.right_operand = r;
    newTreeNode->tree_node_type = operator_type;

    // and return the tree_node
    return newTreeNode;
}

void free_expression_tree(tree_node **pnode)
    {
    // Free all dynamically reserved memory and set *pnode to NULL.
    if ((*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand && (*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
    {
    free_expression_tree(&(*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand);
    (*pnode)->the_operator_node.left_operand = NULL;
    }

    if ((*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand && (*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
    {
    free_expression_tree(&(*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand);
    (*pnode)->the_operator_node.right_operand = NULL;
    }

    printf("Free: ");
    if ((*pnode)->tree_node_type == operator_type)
        {
        printf("%c, ", (*pnode)->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        free(*pnode);
        printf("%c, \n", (*pnode)->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%d, ", (*pnode)->the_number);
        free(*pnode);
        printf("%d, \n", (*pnode)->the_number);

    }
    }

void print_tree_postfix(const tree_node *node)
    {
    if (node)
    {
    print_tree_postfix(node->the_operator_node.left_operand);
    print_tree_postfix(node->the_operator_node.right_operand);

    if (node->tree_node_type == number_type)
        {
        printf("%d ", node->the_number);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%c ", node->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        }
    }
    }

void print_tree_infix(const tree_node *node)
    {
    if (node)
    {
    if (node->the_operator_node.right_operand)
        {
        printf("(");
        }

    print_tree_infix(node->the_operator_node.left_operand);

    if (node->tree_node_type == number_type)
        {
        printf("%d", node->the_number);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%c", node->the_operator_node.the_operator);
        }

    print_tree_infix(node->the_operator_node.right_operand);
    if (node->the_operator_node.left_operand)
        {
        printf(")");
        }
    }
    }
static void output_edge_to_visual_graph(char source, const tree_node *dest, FILE* file)
{
    fprintf(file, "  \"%c\" -> \"", source);
    switch (dest->tree_node_type)
    {
        case operator_type:
            fprintf(file, "%c", dest->the_operator_node.the_operator);
            break;
        case number_type:
            fprintf(file, "%d", dest->the_number);
            break;
    }
    fprintf(file, "\"\n");
}

static void output_node_to_visual_graph(const tree_node *node, FILE *file)
{
    if (node != NULL && node->tree_node_type == operator_type)
    {
        const operator_node *op = &(node->the_operator_node);
        if (op->left_operand != NULL && op->right_operand != NULL)
        {
            output_edge_to_visual_graph(op->the_operator, op->left_operand, file);
            output_edge_to_visual_graph(op->the_operator, op->right_operand, file);
            output_node_to_visual_graph(op->left_operand, file);
            output_node_to_visual_graph(op->right_operand, file);
        }
    }
}

void create_visual_graph_from_tree(const tree_node *root, FILE *file)
{
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(file, "digraph G {\n");
        if (root != NULL) output_node_to_visual_graph(root, file);
        fprintf(file, "}\n");
    }
}
```

tree.h:

```
#ifndef TREE_H_
#define TREE_H_

typedef struct
{
    char the_operator;
    struct operand_node_tag *left_operand;
    struct operand_node_tag *right_operand;
} operator_node;

typedef struct operand_node_tag
{
    enum {operator_type, number_type} tree_node_type;
    union
    {
        operator_node the_operator_node;
        int the_number;
    };
} tree_node;

tree_node *create_number_node(int i);
tree_node *create_expression(char op, tree_node *l, tree_node *r);
void free_expression_tree(tree_node **pnode);
// frees all dynamically reserved memory and sets *pnode to NULL.

void print_tree_infix(const tree_node *node);
void print_tree_postfix(const tree_node *node);
void create_visual_graph_from_tree(const tree_node *root, FILE *file);

#endif /* TREE_H_ */
```

Comment: You should show a complete code that can be compiled and run to reproduce the problem. Ideally all input should be hard-coded, otherwise show the input as well. On Linux you could use `valgrind` to check for memory access errors. It would warn about accessing memory that has been `free`d.

Comment: @bodo: If you type `[mcve]` in a comment, you get a link to [mcve], which is exactly what you described here. To the OP: Please read that link, but also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `free()` does not clean the freed memory, this would be a waste of resources. You can of course provide a custom `free()` function, which clears the memory, if your platform has a function like `malloc_usable_size()`.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying I might actually free the memory? Makes sense. 
In that case wondering why my code is showing memory leaks. I'm working in windows, so I'm using DrMemory to check for leaks.
It shows I've got a leak on: 
tree_node *root = create_expression('+', create_number_node(12), rootkeer);
Yet I'm quite sure I'm freeing this memory, I'm seeing the address being freed in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
free(*pnode);
```

directly followed by e.g.

```
printf("%d, \n", (*pnode)->the_operator_node.the_operator);
```

In the second statement you dereference a pointer you just passed to `free`, so the memory that the pointer is pointing to is no longer owned by your program, and any attempt to dereference the pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You simply can't use memory once it has been free'd.

The solution to this is to not have that second `printf` call after the call to `free`, especially since it will only print what the first `printf` call prints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I understand referencing a freed address might result in undefined behaviour. I'm only printing the value to check wether the free has been executed or not. I'm assuming it would print some random memory value instead of the memory I have just freed right?

I've checked memory leaks using a tool called DrMemory and it confirms the fact I've got memory leaks present. Which is why I'm assuming the memory hasn't been properly freed.

Comment: @MichaelVanDerBend "*I understand referencing a freed address might result in undefined behaviour.*" - evidently not.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer *does* (not "might") produce UB.  That could manifest in any way at all, including, but not limited to, behavior that you might expect from dereferencing a valid pointer; crashing the program; and sending a rude text to your mother.  You cannot use that to check whether a pointer has been freed.

Comment: I see, any other way of making sure the memory has been freed? Except doing a memory leak check? DrMemory says I've got 1 leak, yet when I'm debugging I can see 9 frees and 9 mallocs.